# How to call a function when some Ionic or html even loads up

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i have a if  conditions on my html page 
i want to show some data when if condition returns False,
while on the other hand when if returns true i want to execute some function.
I have no clue how to achieve this.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(form.answers[0].answer === 'opt' ||form.answers[0].answer === 'opt_select' ||  form.answers[0].answer ==='chk_select')">
<p>{{form.question}}</p>
{{form.answers[0].answer}}
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="(form.answers[0].answer === 'opt' || form.answers[0].answer === 'opt_select' ||  form.answers[0].answer === 'chk_select')">
<!--- here i want to execute the function---!>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

You can just subscribe to form control changes and execute the function there:

`this.form.get('answers').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    // check the condition and execute the function
  });`